# Diagonal action by $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, schemes

I have a basic question about a certain action
on product of projective lines $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$
by group $\mathbb{Z}/2$ which Sasha introduced in this [MO discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/q/306885).

How does it here exactly work? Sasha noted that 'the group acts diagonally,
and nontrivially on each factor'.

My first guess was that this action swaps just the both factors
a la $(a,b) \mapsto (b,a)$ but it is described the be diagonal, that is
it acts as $(a, b) \mapsto (ga, gb)$ with $g \in \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Which action is here meant? simply the 'minus sign'-action
$(a,b) \mapsto (-a,-b)$ or something else?

#update: As Prof Mosher remarked that's definitely diagonal action and therefore is given by $(ga, gb)$. Now the question is what is $ga$ or in other words how $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acts on $\mathbb{P}^1$? I think that my first idea that it acts by multiply a minus sign fails, because we would obtain a trivial action since
every 'point' in $\mathbb{P}^1$ is given in homogeneous coordinates
as $[x:y] \in \mathbb{P}^1$ up to multiplicative factor therefore
multiplying it by a minus sign doesn't change it. Therefore the
action is trivial.

Otherwise possibly the action by $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is defined
here with 'minus sign' in 'affine' sense, namely that if we take
$\mathbb{P}^1 = Proj(k[X_0, X_1])$ then it acts on affine pieces
on *rings* $k[X_0/X_1]$ and $k[X_1/X_0]$ by multiplication
by $-1$ eg $X_0/X_1 \mapsto -X_0/X_1$?

Answer (score 1):

You've written the action in your post: the action of each $g \in \mathbb Z / 2$ on each factor of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is already given, and then $g$ acts on $(a,b) \in \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ by taking it to $(ga,gb) \in \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$.

Comment: So that's indeed the 'minus sign'-action 
$(a,b) \mapsto (-a,-b)$? 
Therefore it suffice to talk about the action  
$\mathbb{Z}/2$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$. But why is it given by
'minus sign'-action? Isn't it then a trivial action since 
every 'point' in $\mathbb{P}^1$ is given in homogeneous coordinates
as $[x:y] \in \mathbb{P}^1$ up to multiplicative factor therefore 
multiplying it by a minus sign doesn't change it. Therefore the
action is trivial, in contrast to what is clamed.

Comment: Or is the action by $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is defined
here 'minus sign'-action in 'affine' sense, namely that if we take
$\mathbb{P}^1 = Proj(k[X_0, X_1])$ then it acts on affine pieces
on *rings* $k[X_0/X_1]$ and $k[X_1/X_0]$ by multiplication 
by $-1$ eg $X_0/X_1 \mapsto -X_0/X_1$?

Comment: I believe the "minus sign action" refers to that which acts on $\mathbb A^1$ by multiplication by $-1$, leaving $0$ and $\infty$ as fixed points. EDIT: your second comment, which is correct and more formal than mine, popped up just as I hit submit.

Comment: I don't know about a "minus sign" action. What is says in that link that the group $\mathbb Z / 2$ acts nontrivially on each $\mathbb P^1$ factor. One such action, writing $\mathbb P^1 = \mathbb A^1 \cup \infty$, would be $x \mapsto -\frac{1}{x}$.